# Failed to clone https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git

Tags: php, git, rest, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to install **doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle** on **Symfony2** to create a *Rest API*.

Terminal

```
root@symfonyRest:/var/www/Symfony# php5 composer.phar require doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle dev-master
```

Error message

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle (dev-master 3caec48)
    Cloning 3caec4826e58fe47520b591f965b4adcdfc8a6c8


  [RuntimeException]                                                                           
  Failed to clone https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git, git was not found,   
  check that it is installed and in your PATH env.                                             

  sh: 1: git: not found
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "@stable",
        "symfony/yaml": "@stable",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "@stable",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "@stable",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong.. :s

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory: `git was not found, check that it is installed`.  You don't have `git` installed, you need to install it.

Comment: Shame on me !! I thought the git (repository) was not found. Problem because of my bad translation.. But no, it was git ! `apt-get install git` has solved my problem ! Thx, and sorry !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git was not found, check that it is installed
```

You don't have `git` installed.  You should install it, depending on your OS the command it may be different.

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```